# How to pass a variable to a partial in handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm trying to use the lookup function in handlebars to pass a dynamic partial, but it's not quite working for me.

My data is:

```
{
"sections": [
    "about",
    "when",
    "where"
]}
```

Template looks like:

```
   {{#each copy.sections}}
        <section class='section' id='section-{{this}}' aria-labelledby='hed-{{this}}'>
            <h2 class='section__hed' id='hed-{{this}}'>{{this}}</h2>
            {{> graphic/(lookup . 'this') }} // Need to render this dynamically
        </section>
    {{/each}}
```

Basically I'd like the lookup to resolve as:
`{{> graphic/about}}`, `{{> graphic/when}}`, and `{{> graphic/where}}`

Answer (score 0):

If your data is:

```
var copy = {
   "sections": [
   "about",
   "when",
   "where"
]};
```

You only need to specify `{{#each sections }}` instead of `{{#each copy.sections}}`:

```
{{#each sections}}
   <section class='section' id='section-{{this}}' aria-labelledby='hed-{{this}}'>
      <h2 class='section__hed' id='hed-{{this}}'>{{this}}</h2>
      graph/{{ this }} 
   </section>
{{/each}}
```

I couldn't make sense out of your code `{{> graphic/(lookup . 'this') }}`, it does not have a valid syntax, so I assumed what you are trying to do is `graph/{{ this }}`.

Comment: Hmm I don't think this is exactly what I'm looking for. I have to use `copy.sections` as it's coming from a JSON file, and I'm using `gulp-hb` to pull in data (I need to specify what file it's from, thus the copy part). I'm trying to use the dynamic partial. So I need it to resolve as it's own partial. For example, when it loops through the each and hits the first element in the array it would be `{{> graphic/about }}` and pull in that partial.

Comment: Then edit your post and provide a more complete data structure and more clarity on your problem. My answer is based on what you shown with a guess on the name of your data variable.

Comment: One more thing, if you are reading from a json file, what is your json file name? if your json file is called mydata.json, then you get what you want with syntax as `{{> mydata mydata.sections}}`. This is the part I could make sense out from what you provided, because your data structure does not have anything related to the `graphic`.